# Remove break line in textView Android

Tags: java, android

My textview shows strings like this

```
apple
some break line
banana
some break line
grape
potato
some break line
```

i'd like to know join all this words, with only break line like this

```
apple
banana
grape
potato
carrot
```

i'm using replace all but doesnt works

```
food = food.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
```

Comment: what is the result you are getting

Comment: for example  word (4 break line) other word break line. i'd like to remove excess of break lines

Comment: can you show your result more accurately?

Comment: for example. in my text view show this    orange \n\n\ngrape\apple\n\n\ncarrot    i'd like remove the \n and show this grape\napple\ncarrot   with only one \n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `StringTokenizer`  here is an example that will only report strings as tokens

```
    String test = "\n\n\ttest\n\n\r\rtest\r\r\n\ntest";
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(test);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String string = tokenizer.nextToken();
        builder.append(string).append('\n');
    }
    System.out.println("Final Result:\n" + builder.toString());
```

This produces:

```
Final Result:
test
test
test
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a replace:

```
mTexto.getText().toString().replace("\n", " "));
```